# Script não obedece o loop na exibição de botão

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Estou fazendo um programa simples, porém estou com um erro no momento de exibir as informações, ocorre o seguinte, após gerar o loop eu clico em um dos botões, e independente do botão que eu clicar, sempre é exibido o primeiro resultado.
Se alguém souber uma maneira de resolver isso, e deseja compartilhar, seria de extrema importância.

```
<div id="busca">
    <h1>Olá, seja bem-vindo</h1>
    <p id="informativo">Digite um número abaixo</p>

    <form method="post" action="">
        <input id="cpf_processo" type="text" size="50" name="num_usuario" required="required"
               placeholder="Digite aqui">
        <input id="consultar" type="submit" name="vis_numero" value="CONSULTAR">
        <br>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function visTabela(id) {
        var numero = document.getElementById("numero");
        var informativo = document.getElementById("informativo");
        if (numero.style.display === "none") {
            numero.style.display = "revert";
        } else {
            numero.style.display = "none";
            informativo.style.display = "revert";
        }
    }
</script>

<?php
$numUsuario = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'num_usuario', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$visNumero = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'vis_numero', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

if ($visNumero == true) {

    for ($i = 0; $numUsuario > $i; $i++) {

        $infor = "<div id='informativo' style='display: block'> clique no botão acima</div> <br>";
        $mosNum = "<div id='numero' style='display: none'>O número do botão: $i </div>";
        $botao = "<button style='margin-top: 4%' onclick='visTabela()'>Mostrar número</button> ";

        echo "$botao";
        echo "$infor";
        echo "$mosNum";
    }
}
```

Comment: O que exatamente você quer? explique com mais detalhes, antes de mais nada **sugiro** que veja como criar um [mre] e [Como fazer uma boa perguna?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), edite sua pergunta, adicione detalhes e esclarecimentos, suas tentativas, o passo-a-passo de como funciona e/ou era para funcionar, entre outros..

Comment: Geralmente nesse tipo de coisa precisa enviar o ID e dele vc abre o certo, no caso vc não esta usando o id pra nada.

Answer (score 0):

Na função abaixo, você supostamente recebe o id, porem vc não esta enviando ele primeiramente e tbm não esta o utilizando, por isso não da erro, então se vc fizer ao invez disso:

```
function visTabela(id) {
        var numero = document.getElementById("numero");
        var informativo = document.getElementById("informativo");
        if (numero.style.display === "none") {
            numero.style.display = "revert";
        } else {
            numero.style.display = "none";
            informativo.style.display = "revert";
        }
    }
```

fazer isso:

```
function visTabela(id) {
        var numero = "numero-"+id;
        var numero = document.getElementById(numero);
        var informativo = document.getElementById("informativo");
        if (numero.style.display === "none") {
            numero.style.display = "revert";
        } else {
            numero.style.display = "none";
            informativo.style.display = "revert";
        }
    }
```

e mudar a parte do php para isso:

```
$numUsuario = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'num_usuario', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$visNumero = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'vis_numero', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

if ($visNumero == true) {

    for ($i = 0; $numUsuario > $i; $i++) {

        $infor = "<div id='informativo' style='display: block'> clique no botão acima</div> <br>";
        $mosNum = "<div id='numero-".$i."' style='display: none'>O número do botão: $i </div>";
        $botao = "<button style='margin-top: 4%' onclick='visTabela(".$i.")'>Mostrar número</button> ";

        echo $botao;
        echo $infor;
        echo $mosNum;
    }
}
```

Vc vera que funcionara do jeito que espera, o problema era que todos estavam com o msm id, então ele só pegava o primeiro, entendeu?

Comment: Excelente solução, muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente